# Classify tree height and age

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, features, classification

I am doing the classification of mangrove trees according to their species, height, and etc by using QGIS. I have done the species classification part. I would like to know how can I differentiate these trees by their height?

Let's say I have a few categories:

- 0-5m
- 6-10m
- 11-15m

How can I classify them using QGIS?

Is remote sensing able to classify them automatically or should I go to the site and collect the data and input as attributed data (e.g. CSV)?

Comment: Hi Diana, what type of imagery are using for your project? did you end up using any of the approaches mentioned below? If so, which one?

Answer (score 2):

Most classification methods would not catch the difference between different tree heights automatically.
You would need to train your classification method using local information on where the different heights of trees are located and also other relevant land-use classes, such as irrigated farm land, water, grasslands etc.

All in all, your best bet for doing a classification where you have three different mangrove classes is a supervised classification.

As an extra thing to keep in mind, consider using a combination of SAR and optical data for your classification, as these data sources compliment each other well, when looking at detailed classification of woodlands.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach here would be to just categorize them like you have done in your question. You have your mangrove species map so you know the mangrove extent. You could then use the raster calculator tool (or a little python) to classify tree height using thresholds.

You could try a supervised approach but it seems more effort than its worth to just categorize your data